# Zabbix Agent Not Starting on AIX

Tags: aix, zabbix

I am trying to run zabbix on my AIX VM, this is the startup script

```
mkgroup zabbix
mkuser pgrp='zabbix' groups='zabbix' zabbix
mkdir /etc/zabbix
mkdir /var/log/zabbix/
chown -R zabbix:zabbix /var/log/zabbix/
mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/
mkdir -p /var/run/zabbix/
chown -R zabbix:zabbix /var/run/zabbix/
cp zabbix_agents/bin/zabbix_* /bin/
cp zabbix_agents/sbin/zabbix_agent* /sbin/
cp -r zabbix_agents/conf/zabbix_agent* /etc/zabbix/
ln  -s /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf  /usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf
mv  /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf_bck
cat > /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf << EOF
#DebugLevel=3
DebugLevel=4
EnableRemoteCommands=1
LogRemoteCommands=1
Hostname=ch3axsvwas02
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
Server=sv2lxzbxps11
ServerActive=sv2lxzbxps11
LogFileSize=512
Timeout=30
RefreshActiveChecks=300
StartAgents=1
MaxLinesPerSecond=50
AllowRoot=0
Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd/
EOF
zabbix_agentd
```

When I run the script however I get the following output

```
004-688 Group "zabbix" exists.
3004-689 User "zabbix" exists.
mkdir: 0653-358 Cannot create /etc/zabbix.
/etc/zabbix: Do not specify an existing file.
mkdir: 0653-358 Cannot create /var/log/zabbix/.
/var/log/zabbix/: Do not specify an existing file.
ln: 0653-421 /usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf exists.
    Specify -f to remove /usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf before linking.
zabbix_aix.sh[32]: zabbix_agentd:  not found.
```

When I try to run it stand alone too it's the same output

```
# zabbix_agentd
ksh: zabbix_agentd:  not found.
```

The same zabbix script has run on other AIX Hosts, could this have something to do with permission or system configuration.

I am running on AIX version 6

Comment: Where is the zabbix_agentd binary? Is it part of `zabbix_agents/bin/zabbix_*`, and thus ending up in /bin/, or is it part of `zabbix_agents/sbin/zabbix_agent*` and so ending up in /sbin?

Comment: Hi its in /sbin

Answer (score 1):

Are `/sbin` and `/bin` in the `PATH`? Otherwise you should run the agent with the full path to the binary: `/bin/zabbix_agentd`

Also, is `zabbix_agentd` executable?

Comment: Its in /sbin and is executable